# Linq insert statement will not work

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am new to Linq and I am trying to mess around with it on the Northwind database. I  have looked online on how to do inserts but the following cod does not seem to work. Why woun't this data go into the Suppliers table?

```
using (LinqDataClassesDataContext northwind = new LinqDataClassesDataContext())
        {

            Supplier newSupplier = new Supplier 
            { 
                SupplierID = northwind.Suppliers.Max(id => id.SupplierID) + 1,
                CompanyName = "Doe Electrical",
                ContactName = "John Doe",
                ContactTitle = "Mr.",
                Address = "123 Fake Street",
                City = "Dublin",
                Region = null,
                PostalCode = "123456",
                Country = "Ireland",
                Phone = "123456789",
                Fax = "987654321",
                HomePage = "Hello World!"
            };

            northwind.Suppliers.InsertOnSubmit(newSupplier);

            try
            {
                northwind.SubmitChanges();
                Console.WriteLine("Inserted");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                Console.ReadLine();
                throw;
            }

        }
```

The Program runs to completion with no exceptions but the data does not get inserted.
Thanks

I have since updated the Supplier ID

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Suppliers] (
[SupplierID]   INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[CompanyName]  NVARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,
[ContactName]  NVARCHAR (30) NULL,
[ContactTitle] NVARCHAR (30) NULL,
[Address]      NVARCHAR (60) NULL,
[City]         NVARCHAR (15) NULL,
[Region]       NVARCHAR (15) NULL,
[PostalCode]   NVARCHAR (10) NULL,
[Country]      NVARCHAR (15) NULL,
[Phone]        NVARCHAR (24) NULL,
[Fax]          NVARCHAR (24) NULL,
[HomePage]     NTEXT         NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Suppliers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SupplierID] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Any errors / exceptions?

Comment: Have you debugged the code are you getting any errors if so what is the error also is this `SupplierID` an Auto Increment Column` if so then remove it

Comment: Define "does not work".

Comment: I am using a local copy of northwind through a mdf file. When I run the code above the program completes with no exceptions. However when I view the table data. nothing new has been added.

Comment: What happens if you remove the line: `SupplierID = northwind.Suppliers.Max(id => id.SupplierID) + 1,`

Comment: Are you restarting/rebuilding the program after you have inserted the row but before you view the contents? Could Visual Studio copy a fresh copy of the database file each time?

Comment: I tried viewing both while the proggram was still running but finished the submit and after when the program was not running. The line with SupplierID = northwind.Suppliers.Max(id => id.SupplierID) + 1 was entered afterwards as I thought it may have been something to do with the primary key not auto incrementing but didn't make a difference.

Answer (score -1):

```
 using (var northwind = new DataClassesDataContext())
            {

                var newSupplier = new Supplier();

                    //SupplierID = northwind.Suppliers.Max(id => id.SupplierID) + 1,
                newSupplier.CompanyName = "Doe Electrical";
                newSupplier.ContactName = "John Doe";
                newSupplier.ContactTitle = "Mr.";
                newSupplier.Address = "123 Fake Street";
                newSupplier.City = "Dublin";
                newSupplier.Region = null;
                newSupplier.PostalCode = "123456";
                newSupplier.Country = "Ireland";
                newSupplier.Phone = "123456789";
                newSupplier.Fax = "987654321";
                newSupplier.HomePage = "Hello World!";


                northwind.Suppliers.InsertOnSubmit(newSupplier);


                try
                {
                    northwind.SubmitChanges();

                    //get identity id  for supplierid
                    var supplierid = newSupplier.SupplierID.ToString();

                    Console.WriteLine("Inserted");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    throw;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Hey Friend,kindly send the code ...see  you have to specify identity for Supplierid in sql

Comment: I have added the table definition to the post

Comment: I added sql script its working for me,check whether EF datacontext  is properly suited

Comment: @KarthikDevarajan Please don't just post code. Always briefly explain what is different and why it should solve the problem.

Comment: @GertArnold -check my following post code...i commented                                                              SupplierID = northwind.Suppliers.Max(id => id.SupplierID) + 1; and  verify my code

Comment: @KarthikDevarajan The comment doesn't *explain* anything. The point is  that not only the OP will read this answer. Other readers won't take the effort to compare two walls of code. Why do you think that your code would solve the problem? Code-only answers are likely to be deleted as "low quality posts".